# Return a list to a addCircles() popup, Leaflet shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Is there a way to create a popup for a leaflet() shiny app that returns a list?  The idea being it's a one-to-many relationship, so we needed two tables (the first to create sites, and the second to create popup information).

```
#Table_1 - Sites
SiteID  Lat            Long 
A       32.77207993    -109.0014077
B       33.09301968    -104.3500967
C       33.08755703    -104.3630058


#Table_2 - Site Info
SiteID  Owner    Type 
A       Frank    Farm
A       Howard   Home
B       Bird     Tree
C       Fish     Pool

# ################################################################################################
# ################################################################################################
#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)


################################################################################################
################################################################################################
#UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(), 
    dashboardSidebar(), 
    dashboardBody( leafletOutput(outputId = 'mapA'))
)

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
server <- function(input, output) {

    ##The Map
    output$mapA <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = Table_1) %>%
            addCircles(
                lat = ~Lat,
                lon = ~Long,
                popup = paste(
                 "SiteID: ", Table_1$SiteID,
                 "Owner: ", Table_2$Owner,
                 "Type: ", Table_2$Type)
             )
        )
     )}
}

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The popup output of SiteID 'A' being something like...

```
SiteID: A
Owner: Frank, Howard
Type: Farm, Home
```

Comment: What is `add_scatterplot`, it doesn't seem to be from leaflet package?

Comment: @HubertL  Opps.  I apologize.  ```add_scatterplot``` is meant for seperate mapping package other than leaflet.  It should be ```addCircles()```.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate your data first:

```
Table_2 %<>% 
    group_by(SiteID) %>% 
    summarise_all(paste, collapse = ",")
```

Then use HTML tags to format the popup:

```
popup = paste(
    "<B>SiteID</B>: ", Table_2$SiteID, "<BR>",
    "<B>Owner</B>: ", Table_2$Owner, "<BR>",
    "<B>Type</B>: ", Table_2$Type)
```

[image: NicePopup]